# How can I build golang app with tags using gin?

Tags: go, graphicsmagick, negroni

A critical component of my golang app uses the ported [GraphicsMagick library](https://github.com/rainycape/magick) which requires building the library with `-tags gm`.

For example:

`go build -tags gm`

However, I'm building the web service based on the [negroni framework](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni) and running it with [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) which allows me to run the app with the command `gin`. I cannot find any way of passing build tags to gin. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but it appears codegangsta/gin is abandoned so support for build tags simply won't be added. Instead, Github user omeid has compiled a patch and using his [fork of gin](https://github.com/omeid/gin) will allow use of build tags.

```
go get github.com/omeid/gin
gin -tags gm
```